# Resample in pandas without changing date

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I download daily stock price data using pandas:

```
df = web.DataReader('YHOO', 'yahoo', '1/1/2004', '1/31/2004')['Close']
```

I want closing prices on the first trading day of each week. This is typically Monday, but will be Tuesday if Monday is a holiday.

So I try resampling:

```
df.resample('W-MON', how='last')
```

and get this:

```
Date
2004-01-05    46.900002
2004-01-12    49.740002
2004-01-19    48.110001
2004-01-26    48.160000
2004-02-02    46.980000
```

Pandas is very cleverly giving me data with only Mondays. But `2004-01-19` was a holiday, and is actually not in `df`:

```
Date
2004-01-02    45.400002
2004-01-05    46.900002
...
2004-01-15    48.090000
2004-01-16    48.110001
2004-01-20    47.660000
2004-01-21    47.380001
...
```

Is there a way to have it give the first date each week *from the dataframe* that is on or after a Monday? (So, the result above, except with `2004-01-19` replaced with `2004-01-20`.)

Comment: IIUC : `from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
bday_us = CustomBusinessDay(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar()) df.loc[df.index + bday_us].resample('W-MON', how='last)` gives: 

`Out[27]:
Date
2004-01-05    46.900002
2004-01-12    49.740002
2004-01-19    48.110001
2004-01-26    48.160000
2004-02-02    46.980000`

Comment: Isn't that the same output I have with my resample?

Comment: Curiously yes but I feel that this is the right approach as you remove the Monday that falls on the Holiday

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense move `2004-01-19` *back* to `2004-01-16`? After all, the price on `2004-01-16`, `48.110001`, is the price used in the resampled value for `2004-01-19`. Associating that price with `2004-01-20` doesn't make as much sense since `2004-01-20` was part of the next time group.

Comment: Yes, @unutbu you're certainly right. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If we choose to move missing dates such as `2004-01-19` *back* to the last date within the resampling time period (e.g. `2004-01-16`), then that could be accomplished by applying the `resampling` not only to the closing prices, but also to the `Date` itself:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as pdata

df = pdata.get_data_yahoo('YHOO', start='2004-1-1', end='2004-1-31')
df['Date'] = df.index
df = df[['Close', 'Date']]

result = df.resample('W-MON', how='last')
result = result.set_index('Date')
```

yields

```
                Close
Date                 
2004-01-05  46.900002
2004-01-12  49.740002
2004-01-16  48.110001
2004-01-26  48.160000
2004-01-30  46.980000
```

Since `df` has a `Date` column, `df.resample('W-MON', how='last')` finds both the last price and the last Date in each resampling group.

---

To solve the original problem, where missing dates such as `2004-01-19` are replaced by the next date present in `df`, you could use

```
In [343]: df.index.searchsorted(result.index)
Out[343]: array([ 1,  6, 11, 15, 20])
```

to find the ordinal index where the dates in `result.index` would "fit" into `df.index` so as to maintain sorted order. These indices tell us the date in `df.index` which comes *on or after* the corresponding date in `result.index`:

```
In [349]: df.iloc[[1,6,11,15]].index
Out[349]: DatetimeIndex(['2004-01-05', '2004-01-12', '2004-01-20', '2004-01-26'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=u'Date', freq=None)
```

Then use these ordinal indices to reassign dates from `df.index` back into `result.index`:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as pdata

df = pdata.get_data_yahoo('YHOO', start='2004-1-1', end='2004-1-31')['Close']

result = df.resample('W-MON', how='last')
idx = df.index.searchsorted(result.index)
# np.clip reduces the index by 1 if a date in result.index comes after all dates in df.index
idx = np.clip(idx, 0, len(df)-1)
result.index = df.iloc[idx].index
```

yields

```
Date
2004-01-05    46.900002
2004-01-12    49.740002
2004-01-20    48.110001
2004-01-26    48.160000
2004-01-30    46.980000
Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

Note that the last date gets move to `2004-01-30` because `2004-02-02` is also not in `df.index` and the last available date in `df.index` is `2004-01-30`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just query for any day-of-week that is less than the previous date:

```
weekdays = np.array(map(lambda x: x.weekday(), df.index))
df[weekdays < np.roll(weekdays, 1)]
```

This works because the `weekday` starts at `0` for Monday and increments from there. So the *first day of the week* will have a `weekday` that is less than the previous date.